# How to get hexadecimal number of a char?

Tags: c#, ascii

I have to develop a `Windows Mobile C# app` to compare chars and get the ascii code

This is my pseudocode:

```
    public void getAscii(char c) 
    {
        int ascii_n = c.GetAscii(); //or something that gives me the hexadec number
        //You know; a=97, b=98...

        if (ascii_n > 12 && ascii_n < 23)
        { 
            //code lines
        }
        else if (ascii_n > 24 && ascii_n < 55)
        {
            //more code lines
        }
    }
```

Any idea about how can I do it??

Comment: What do you want to do with non-ASCII characters, that is, Unicode characters?

Comment: Nothing! I'll compare just `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`

Comment: So, you want to ignore '!`?

Comment: Just so you know, this functionality is already available in the framework in the form of `Char.IsUpper`, `Char.IsLower` and `Char.IsDigit`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting The ASCII Value of a character in a C# string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002909/getting-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-in-a-c-sharp-string)

Comment: Yes! @JohnSaunders I dont need `"#$#&%/&(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an hex representation of a char, just a conversion to an integer could be enough

```
char c = '\n';
int ascii_n = (int)c;
Console.WriteLine(ascii_n);   // = 10
```

also for char higher than 255

```
char c = '∙';
int a = (int)c;
Console.WriteLine(a);   // = 8729
```

Comment: Let me try @Steve Thank You so much!

Comment: Aren't both examples technically Unicode? Just that ASCII has the same values as Unicode?

Comment: Yes they are both unicode, it is just to show that it works also for values higher than 255