# Shuffle characters of a string based on a key

Tags: c#

I have the following String:

```
String characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
```

I need to create two strings from it:

1. A string obtained simply by reordering the characters;
2. A string obtained by selecting 10 characters and reordering them.

So for (1) I would get, for example:

```
String characters = "jkDEF56789hisGHIbdefpqraXYZ1234txyzABCcglmnoRSTUVWuvwJKLMNOPQ0";
```

And for (2) I would get, for example:

```
String shortList = "8GisIbH9hd";
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I could just change to Char Array and order by randomly by a Guid.

However I want to specify some kind of key (maybe a guid?) and for that key the result or reordering and of selecting the shortList must be the same.

Does this make sense?

Comment: your problem is not clear. How can you "reorder" your first string "based on a Guid". I think you chose the wrong word.
Could you explain what you really want step by step and what is your problem now?

Comment: what is the exact output of (1) and (2)?

Comment: Are you looking to encode an arbitrary reordering of (1)62 and (2)10 characters in a Guid?  You have 62 unique characters, so each could be represented by a 6 bit number.  Thus an arbitrary reordering of 10 characters requires no more than 60 bits, and so could be encoded in a Guid (128 bits).  An arbitrary reordering of all 62 characters requires more than 128 bits however, so your Guid would need to index into a table.

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. I just updated my answer. Basically I want to reorder a string characters and selecting a portion of that string also reordered but the results would always be same according to a key ... So if I use as key "ksjdhkjhurer" then the results would only change if I change that key.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert your GUID string to an int array of its ascii/utf/whatever codes like here
[Getting The ASCII Value of a character in a C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002909/getting-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-in-a-c-sharp-string).
then iterate over this array with something along lines of this (note: this is pseudocode):

```
 string res="";
 for(elem in intconvertedGUIDstring) res+= characters[elem%(characters.count)];
```

for the task [2] you could reverse  your Characters i.e. like here [Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string) 
and use the c# string function left() to truncate it before running it through  the same procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash function with a good distribution value as seed for comparison between elements. Here's a sample:

```
static ulong GetHash(char value, ulong seed)
{
   ulong hash = seed * 3074457345618258791ul;
   hash += value;
   hash *= 3074457345618258799ul;
   return hash;
}
```

And use this function for comparison:

```
static void Main()
{
   var seed = 53ul;
   var str = "ABCDEFHYUXASPOIMNJH";
   var shuffledStr = new string(str.OrderBy(x => GetHash(x, seed)).ToArray());
   Console.WriteLine(shuffledStr);
}
```

Now every time you order by seed 53 you'll get the same result, and if you seed by 54 you'll get a different result.