# Converting Character to Ascii

Tags: c#, ascii

I've been creating a code breaking software and I need to convert the characters from a text file into ascii numbers to allow the shift. I have left my code below but could someone explain how I could do this?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CipherDecoder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileText = @"C:/Users/Samuel/Documents/Computer_Science/PaDS/caeserShiftEncodedText";

            string cipherText = File.ReadAllText(fileText);

            string output = @"C:\\Users\Samuel\Documents\Computer_Science\PaDS\output.txt\";

            char[] cipherChars = new char[691];

            int j = 0;

            foreach (char s in cipherText)
            {
                cipherChars[j] = s;

                j++;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < cipherChars.Length; i++)
            {
                cipherChars[i] = cipherChars[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an implicit conversion from `char` to `int` to give you the UTF-16 code unit value as a number. For ASCII characters, that will be the same as the ASCII value. Your current code is a bit odd though - the second loop doesn't do anything, and the first would be simpler as `char[] cipherChars = cipherText.ToCharArray();`

Comment: possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002909/getting-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-in-a-c-sharp-string

Comment: Nice Explanation @JonSkeet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To  get the int values into an int array you could just do this with as a LINQ select. For example:

```
 string fileText = @"C:/Users/Samuel/Documents/Computer_Science/PaDS/caeserShiftEncodedText";

 int [] charactersAsInts = File.ReadAllText(fileText).Select(chr => (int)chr).ToArray();
```

Comment: I receive the error: CS1061  C# 'string' does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method '' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Try add `using System.Linq;` to get the .Select extension method. You may also need to add a reference. Are you using VisualStudio?

Comment: You might also need to add a reference to System.Core to your project (if using VisualStudio)

Comment: That was indeed the error. All sorted and working now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can,

```
var asciiNumbersArray = cipherText.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

If you cast a char to int you get the ascii number in decimal system.