# C# - regex finding all ascii enclosed in ' ' and convert them to hex ascii output

Tags: c#, regex

I write a converter for user input data, which converts number value strings and ascii characters enclosed in `' '` to hex representation. Number entering works fine with:

```
string TestText = "lorem, 'C', 127, 0x06, '#' ipsum";
TestText = Regex.Replace(
    TestText, 
    " +\\d{1,3}", 
    (MatchEvaluator)(match => Convert.ToByte(match.Value).ToString("X2")));         
Out.Text = TestText;
```

But how can I detect ascii chars enclosed in `' '` and convert them to a hex string like: `'C'` will be `43` and `'+'` becomes `2B`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly cast your lambda with `(MatchEvaluator)`

Comment: Personally I do not know C#, but using what you have asked to do a quick search in the stack overflow questions, I found these two questions with accepted answers here.

[Converting Numbers between hex and dec in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)
AND
[Getting the ascii value of a character in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002909/getting-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-in-a-c-sharp-string)

Both have accepted answers, both should help you with your problem.

Comment: Your regex is capturing the `0` of the `0x06`

Comment: xanatox, thx I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to match the regular expression `'[^']'`. This looks for all characters that are not `'` but which are enclosed in `'`.

Then, in your match evaluator, you get the character in the middle, and convert it to a hexadecimal string. To do that, first cast the `char` to an `int` and then you can use `ToString("x2")`:

```
TestText = Regex.Replace(TestText, "'[^']'",
    (MatchEvaluator)(match => ((int)match.Value[1]).ToString("x2")));
```

Comment: Should this not be
    '[^']+'
As your example will only match a single character between apostrophes.

Comment: @Rohaq I am under the impression that that is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a RegEx to capture the character inside the `'`s: `"'(.)'"`

Then you need to convert that character to its hex equivalent, like so: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(match.Groups[1].Value).First().ToString("X2")`

so your final code would look like this:

```
string TestText = "lorem, 'C', 127, 0x06, '#' ipsum '+'";
TestText = Regex.Replace(TestText, @" +\d{1,3}", match => Convert.ToByte(match.Value).ToString("X2"));         
TestText = Regex.Replace(TestText, "'(.)'", match => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(match.Groups[1].Value).First().ToString("X2"));
Out.Text = TestText;
```

Note that, as pointed out in the comments, your RegEx is currently matching the `0` at the beginning of `0x06`, which may not be what you want.