# How can I convert a number's digits into ASCII bytes?

Tags: c#, ascii

If I have `int x = 24`, how can I convert that into a 2-byte array where the first byte stores the value for `2` (`50`) and the second byte stores the value for `4` (`52`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp with the variation of adding a ToString() to the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Text.Encoding.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(x.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to convert to a String first, then convert that to bytes.

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the division and modulo operators:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { (byte)(48 + x / 10), (byte)(48 + x % 10) };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x_int = 24;
string x_string = x_int.ToString();
var x_bytes = (from x in x_string select Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray();
```