# how to return ASCII code in C#

Tags: c#

how i can return ascii code of a specific string typed in the textbox and show it in same text box?

the code below returns System.byte[], what is the problem?

```
string value = textBox1.Text;
textBox1.Text=Convert.ToString (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("v"));
```

[this answer doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ASCII value of string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: it doesn't work @CDspace

Comment: String.valueOf((int)'v')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` returns a byte array. You can't just convert the whole object to a string, or you get the class type (`System.byte[]` in this case).

Instead, call `ToString` on each item (byte) in the collection:

```
textBox1.Text =
    string.Join(",", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello").Select(b => b.ToString()));
```

Output:

```
"104,101,108,108,111"
```

---

Or if you don't want a delimiter:

```
textBox1.Text = new string(
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello").SelectMany(b => b.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Output:

```
"104101108108111"
```