# Check For Special Characters without using Regex

Tags: c#

i m a newbie in C# code , i need help with validating special characters without using regex , can someone help me?

i m using this code ATM and want to make it works without regex

```
else if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox2.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]+$")==false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name may not contain any special characters");
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: because in my project the use of regex is prohibited

Comment: Regex has its cons, but this is one of the cases where it *may* be used effectively.

Comment: there are many ways to do this... something like 

foreach(char c in string s) {//and then check against a generic list or something.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex solution isn't really bad, but if Regex is prohibited, you can do the following:

```
textBox2.Text.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

Update:

Since you want  (space) too:

```
textBox2.Text.All(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || c == ' ');
```

Note that `Char.IsLetter` will return true for any Unicode letter. A more strict version would be:

```
textBox2.Text.All(c => (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c == ' '));
```

You get the idea. Basically, we go through all the characters and see if it is in the `A-Z` or the `a-z` range or a space.

Needs `using System.Linq;`. The same can be achieved using a simple loop too.

Comment: [`char.IsLetter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx#remarksToggle) covers considerably more ground than the character class `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: @NicholasCarey - Yes, I had updated to include the more strict version. Refresh :)

Answer (score 2):

We'll, you can do that lots of different ways. For instance,

- A positive test, using Linq makes things nice and declarative:

  ```
  public bool isValid( string s )
  {
    Func<char,bool> valid = c => { c == ' ' || ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' || c <= 'Z' ) } ;
    return s.All(valid) ;
  }
  ```
- Ditto for a negative test using Linq

  ```
  public bool isInvalid( string s )
  {
    Func<char,bool> valid = c => { c == ' ' || ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' || c <= 'Z' ) } ;
    return s.Any(!valid) ;
  }
  ```
- Linq won't necessarily be the fastest way to do this so you might to simply simply iterate over the string, old-school:

  ```
  public bool isValid( string s )
  {
    bool valid = true ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; valid  && i < s.Length ; ++i )
    {
      char c = s[i] ;
      valid = c == ' ' || ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) ;
    }
      return valid ;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably loop through the string and compare the characters against ascii codes

[How to get ASCII value of string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp)

Check if it's in the upper case and lower case ascii code ranges