# Get numeric value of all characters in a string

Tags: c#, ascii

I want to get the decimal ASCII value of a string in C#, for instance:

`"abc123s"` would be: `97 98 99 49 50 51 115`  `(979899495051115)`
'f1c3s1"`would be:`102 49 99 51 115 49`or`1024999511549`

I tried `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int.Parse` but they do not result in  the desired effect.

What method can I use for this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: string input = "I want to get the decimal ASCII value of a string in C#, for instance";
            byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

Comment: Strings in C# are Unicode, not ASCII. If all your characters are in the ASCII character set, then you can just use the Unicode character code as it is a subset of ASCII. Then you just convert each `char` value to `int`. The `Convert.ToInt32` works fine for that if you use it on each character, not on the whole string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're only working with ASCII strings, you can cast each character of the `string` to a `byte` to get the ASCII representation. You can roll the results back into a `string` using `ToString` on the values:

```
string str = "abc123s";
string outStr = String.Empty;

foreach (char c in str)
    outStr += ((byte) c).ToString();
```

You could also get the `byte` values as an array, and make the results into a `string` using `String.Join`:

```
byte[] asciiVals = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
outStr = String.Join(String.Empty, asciiVals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string all = "";

all = String.Join(String.Empty, "abc123s".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Convert.ToInt16()` in combination with a loop for each character and add the int Results as string together.

You shouldn't use Byte because every Char is a Int16.