# how to convert string to ASCII in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to convert a string to ASCII and I added one button of convert to ASCII and 2 text boxes:

example of what should I need to get:
for input text@gg.com I need to get: 116 101 120 116 064 103 103 046 099 111 109
for some reason I always get 78-74-40-67-67-2E-63-6F-6D

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ascii
{
  public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char c in TextBox1.Text)
        {
             TextBox3.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { });
        }
    }

    protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

  }
}
```

Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: Strings are already represented using Unicode, which is a superset of ASCII. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to display your characters as a sequence of ASCII codes?

Comment: int.Parse will fail unless TextBox3.Text contains a valid number.  You'll need to explain further what exactly you are trying to do though

Comment: You can only convert the characters of a string to ascii int. Did you mean to do: `int.Parse(c)`?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: You _really_ need to show an example of what you are trying to do here. Are you parsing numbers into characters? Like `65 66 67 => ABC` ?

Comment: I need to get string  in textbox1 and convert it to ASCII(int) in Textbox3. @ja72

Comment: A string can contain multiple characters, each of which will have its own ASCII code. What do you want to show in textbox3 if there are multiple characters in the string?

Comment: @dotNET  for example for input text@gg.com I need to get: 116 101 120 116 064 103 103 046 099 111 109

Comment: @user3385217 please edit this information into the question so that's it's clear what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ASCII value of string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your strings consist only of ASCII characters, you can use:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox3.Text = string.Join(" ", TextBox1.Text.Select(c => (int)c));
}
```

If your strings consist of non-ASCII characters, then their UTF-16 code units will be returned. If this is not desirable, you should include a check:

```
    if (TextBox1.Text.Any(c => c > 127))
         TextBox3.Text = "Invalid string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert the characters to ASCII and display their codes in decimal:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox3.Text = String.Join(" ", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text));
}
```

Please note that this code first converts the text to ASCII, which covers only characters ranging from 0 to 127, so it depends on what you mean by "ASCII". If you want just Unicode number representations of the code points, use Douglas' answer.

Comment: Thanks, it brings me message error BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(TextBox1.Text)); "cannot convert from string to byte[]"

Comment: @user3385217 Ah sorry, edited.

Comment: The output from `BitConverter` is hex.

Comment: Thanks a lotttt! so what is the reason that I get this: 78-74-40-67-67-2E-63-6F-6D instead of this: 116 101 120 116 064 103 103 046 099 111 109?

Comment: @user3385217 -- that is because the output from `BitConverter` is hexadecimal values not integer.

Comment: @DavidTansey Well, it's both hexadecimal and integer.