# How to take char inputs in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I was solving a problem which says that I have to take a character input and print it's ascii value.

I wrote a program like this which works fine.

```
using System;
namespace ASCII_Value
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(s[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But is there a better way that I only take a character input because user can enter a sentence and will get ascii value of the first character which is senseless as it is stated in the problem statement that I should take in a character.

I want that user not to be able to enter more than one character.

Comment: But it doesn't return a character so I cannot store it's value in a character variable.

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        
        foreach(var ascii in asciiBytes){
            Console.WriteLine(ascii);
        }
     }

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Did you not click on the duplicate link? Start there and read the accepted answer, it has a code sample for returning the `char` for the key stroke.