# Simplifying a method?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I've recently took over a project as a personal hobby in a challenge to improve my code quality. I had made this method but I feel like I'm definitely over working it in some way, I feel like there's a really simple way to do it without having to run through a large switch like this??

I know the 0-9 could just be `.ToString()`'d and then parsed to int and returned, but I'm unsure how to merge that idea whilst also considering the rest of the switch cases.

```
public static short ParseHeight(char input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 2;
        case '3':
            return 3;
        case '4':
            return 4;
        case '5':
            return 5;
        case '6':
            return 6;
        case '7':
            return 7;
        case '8':
            return 8;
        case '9':
            return 9;
        case 'a':
            return 10;
        case 'b':
            return 11;
        case 'c':
            return 12;
        case 'd':
            return 13;
        case 'e':
            return 14;
        case 'f':
            return 15;
        case 'g':
            return 16;
        case 'h':
            return 17;
        case 'i':
            return 18;
        case 'j':
            return 19;
        case 'k':
            return 20;
        case 'l':
            return 21;
        case 'm':
            return 22;
        case 'n':
            return 23;
        case 'o':
            return 24;
        case 'p':
            return 25;
        case 'q':
            return 26;
        case 'r':
            return 27;
        case 's':
            return 28;
        case 't':
            return 29;
        case 'u':
            return 30;
        case 'v':
            return 31;
        case 'w':
            return 32;
        default:
            throw new FormatException("The input was not in a correct format: input must be between (0-k)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: One-liner:
return "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".IndexOf(character);

Comment: There's no reason to call `ToString()` on a `char` and parse the result, when you can just subtract the base value of `0` from the `char` value. See marked duplicate. Likewise, all the other letter ranges can be handled by subtracting the appropriate base value and adding an appropriate offset (e.g. `(ch - 'a') + 10` for values where `ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'`)

Comment: I do find it amusing that the exception thrown will tell the caller that they have to provide a value between `0` and `k` (without being specific as to whether other characters like `!`, `%`, `A`, etc. that may be between those values are legal), and yet the method apparently handles letter characters up to `w`.

Comment: @ssk239fk I write a answer regarding this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073572/713789

Comment: It's a little sad that people are so quick to mark a question as duplicate when it is in fact not a duplicate of the question you link to.

Comment: @Adrian don't do that, ever. SO isn't a discussion forum and posting answers to irrrelevant questions doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos removed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
var value = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".IndexOf(input);
if (value == -1)
    throw new FormatException("The input was not in a correct format: input must be between (0-k)");
return value;
```

Comment: That's probably the best solution for this (at least in temrs of simplicity)

Comment: Thank you, this is much simpler, definitely works :)

Answer (score 2):

**For letters:**

You could make use of ascii code

Lets take letter `a` for example, according to [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/) hex code for `a` is `61`, and increments for each letter (`b` is 62 and so on). You want `10`, so you need to substract `51` from each such code.

You can also use the decimal representation of a character from that table. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp) tells you how to get the decimal representation of a char

**For numbers**

Return directly.

---

I'm merely suggesting the algorithm I would use.
I suppose you can implement the code for this yourself

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
public static short ParseHeight(char input)
{
    var res = input - 0;
    if (res <= 57)
        return (short)(res - 48);
    else if (res >= 97)
        return (short)(res - 87);
    else
    {
        throw new FormatException("The input was not in a correct format: input must be between (0-k)");
    }
}
```